# awk Compare 2 files, print match and print just 2 columns of the second file

Tags: awk

I am novice and I am sure it is a silly question but I searched and I didn't find an answer.
I want to select just 2 columns of my file 2. I know how to select one column =$1 and all columns =$0. But If we want just show 2,3, ... column from file2 in my file3, is it possible?

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $1; next} {gsub(/_/,"-",$2);$2=toupper($2);print a[$2]?a[$2]:"NA",$0,a[$2]?a[$2]:"NA"}' $File2 $File1 > file3
```

or

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} {gsub(/_/,"-",$2);$2=toupper($2);print a[$2]?a[$2]:"NA",$0,a[$2]?a[$2]:"NA"}' $File2 $File1 > file3
```

I just want $1 and $2 from file2, this code doesn´t work. I obtain one column with data from $1 and $2

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $1$2; next} {gsub(/_/,"-",$2);$2=toupper($2);print a[$2]?a[$2]:"NA",$0,a[$2]?a[$2]:"NA"}' $File2 $File1 > file3
```

Any solution??

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts here. Could you please post sample Input_file and expected output too here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' ' # call awk  and set row separator 
        BEGIN {
                  FS=OFS=";"     # set input and output field separator
        } 

        # Here you are reading first argument that is File2
        FNR==NR {
                   # Save column2 and column3 separated by OFS that is ; 
                   # from File2 which is first argument, in array a 
                   # whose index/key being second field/column from File2 

                   a[$2] = $2 OFS $3; 

                   # Stop processing go to next line of File1
                   next
        }
        # Here on words you are reading second argument that is File1
        {
              # Global substitution 
              # replace _ with hyphen - in field2/column2 
              gsub(/_/,"-",$2);

              # Uppercase field2/column2 
              $2=toupper($2);

              # If field2 of current file (File1) exists in array a
              # which is created above using File2 then
              # print array value that is your field2 and field3 of File2
              # else print "NA", and then output field separator, 
              # entire line/record of current file

              print ($2 in a ? a[$2] : "NA"), $0

         }' $File2 $File1 > file3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was exactly my problem. And thanks for the explanation, it's alway good to receive a second check !!